# Why jQuery append is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, I have this table structure:

```
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="afterThat"></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

I want to make it something like this;

```
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="afterThat"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

For that, I am using following jQuery but it's not adding this `</tr><tr>`. I can see it's adding like this way. `<tr></tr>` !

Is there anything I am doing wrong OR how can I achieve this?

```
$(".afterThat").after("</tr><tr>");
```

**Update:**

**This is the HTML code I have now:**

```
<table class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny transaction-table">
<thead>        
    <tr class="footable-pagesize">
        <th align="left">Show</th>
        <th class="afterThat">
            <select id="transaction-per-page" class="float-left">
                <option value="5">50 Per Page</option>
                <option value="10">100 Per Page</option>
                <option value="20">150 Per Page</option>
                <option value="50">200 Per Page</option>
            </select>
        </th>            
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" width="">
            <div id="reportrange"  class="primary-icon dateRangePicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" class="footable-expor-pdf" align="right">
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-excel fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Date</th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Description</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: You can only add valid DOM elements. `</tr><tr>` is not  valid DOM element. The DOM is not a string.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300258/how-to-split-a-table-row-with-jquery-insert-tr-between-tds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300258/how-to-split-a-table-row-with-jquery-insert-tr-between-tds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a new `<tr>` and append your two `<th>` inside it :

- Insert a new `<tr>` after your first one : `tr.after('<tr></tr>');`
- Select your `<th>`s to move : `tr.find('th:nth-child(n+3)')`
- Append them to your newly created `<tr>` : `.appendTo(tr.next())`

```js
let tr = $('tr');
tr.after('<tr></tr>');
tr.find('th:nth-child(n+3)').appendTo(tr.next());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>
    <th class="afterThat">second</th>
    <th>third</th>
    <th>fourth</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After looking at your HTML, you should use this code :

```js
let breakingTr = $('th.afterThat');
breakingTr.parent().after('<tr></tr>');
breakingTr.nextAll().appendTo(breakingTr.parent().next());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny transaction-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="footable-pagesize">
      <th align="left">Show</th>
      <th class="afterThat">
        <select id="transaction-per-page" class="float-left">
          <option value="5">50 Per Page</option>
          <option value="10">100 Per Page</option>
          <option value="20">150 Per Page</option>
          <option value="50">200 Per Page</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th data-breakpoints="xs" width="">
        <div id="reportrange" class="primary-icon dateRangePicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
          <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th data-breakpoints="xs" class="footable-expor-pdf" align="right">
        <a href="" class="primary-icon"> <i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="" class="primary-icon"> <i class="fas fa-file-excel fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th data-breakpoints="xs">Date</th>
      <th data-breakpoints="xs">Description</th>
      <th>Transaction Id</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I have added my original HTML code. Can you check it hat is there anything wrong? Becuase still it's not working

Comment: @Shibbir I edited my answer.

Comment: Hero of my Whole Day :)